# How to apply vlookup for multiple sheets with same criteria

Tags: excel, vba

This is My First post in this site.

i am looking for a vlookup  VBA code for my project.

i have Multiple sheets
like sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,....upto sheet7
in these sheets i have different columns and a usernames column (column B) as common.
i have one more sheet8 in same excel work book in that i have only one column with name usernames (with usernames at column A )

now i want to vlookup sheet1 to sheet7 with sheet8 and what ever names are not matching with usernames in sheet8(i.e NA) should be deleted in all sheets from sheet1 to sheet7 and which are matching should be displayed

Please let me know if its possible with VBA code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Kittu. First of all the good news: yes, it is possible. The bad news (for you) is that StackOverflow does not offer "Code for Me" services, it does not "Teach me how to Code", and it is certainly not a VBA tutorial with a "Show me where to Start" site. This is a place for those with existing code with specific problems to get specific help to overcome that problem. As is, this post is too broad for this forum and risks down votes and closure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..then how can you help me ..i am beginner to VBA coding ..know how to do macros but this time as i have multiple sheets trying with coding  ..if you can provide me syntax i can try for my self...

Comment: You will have to loop through all columns B in sheets 1 to 7 and check if the name exists in column A of sheet 8. Here is a hint how to [check existence of a value in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12642375/3219613). Try to write your own code and if you have specific issues then come back and show what you have done.

Comment: @Kittu This site is full of great coding solutions. Most posts offer even several good / different solution (giving you different angles on how to approach the problem). You might want to start with a search such as http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D+compare+sheets