# Delete rows based on a range of conditions (plural)

Tags: excel, vba, range

it's been a while since I've used VBA. I have a range of unique values that I would like to search a table for. And if those values exist in said table, delete the entire row.

I'm able to loop through and delete specific, singular values, but struggling with multiple. I have tried replacing "30ExGEPAc30Q4" (code below) with Range() and an array, but can't quite get it. Here's what I've got so far:

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Sheets("LRP").ListObjects("Data_LRP").Range.Rows.Count

Worksheets("LRP").Activate
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = "30ExGEPAc30Q4" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: using `If`along with `And` like this: `If Cells(x, 1) = "30xGEPAc30Q4" And Cells(x, 2) = "Whatever" Then` Thought you are not referencing the `Cells` or `Rows` to any worksheet, so beware of that. You can nest as many conditionals as you want but that wouldn't be the way to go.

Comment: @Damian, Thanks for the reply! I suppose i should have mentioned that my conditionals are a range of Cells, not static values. I was using the static string "30xGEPAc30Q4" to test if my delete rows loop was working as intended, but I hope to replace it with my dynamic cell range. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642164/check-if-value-exists-in-column-in-vba

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the quick reply! That thread helps accomplish what I have above, but I'm looking to search & delete more than a single value. I'm looking for help replacing their singular search value with a range of values. Searching a range for any values that exist in another range. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you were going to use an array then you would add another loop after `For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1` to check each value in the array. e.g.  `For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)`,  Your `If x = Arr(i)`, add `Next` below the `End If`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're trying to achieve; I have cleaned up some of the unnecessary bits and now you just have to edit x and lastrow as is necessary.

```
Sub test()

Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

'lastrow = Sheets("LRP").ListObjects("Data_LRP").Range.Rows.Count
x = 1
lastrow = 21


'Worksheets("LRP").Activate
Do While x <= lastrow
'    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(x, 1).Value = "30ExGEPAc30Q4" Then
            Rows(x).Delete
            lastrow = lastrow - 1
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
'    Next x

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to play with it a bit but the Do While Loop was the answer. I posted the working product below

Answer (score 0):

For those curious, it ended up looking like this. Thanks for all the help!

```
Sub Cull()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht1row As Long
Dim sht2row As Long
Dim sht2total As Long
Dim DupID As String

Set sht1 = Worksheets("Data Form")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("LRP")
sht2.Activate
sht2total = Worksheets("LRP").ListObjects("Data_LRP").Range.Rows.Count
sht1row = 33

Do While sht1.Cells(sht1row, 2).Value <> ""

DupID = sht1.Cells(sht1row, 2).Value

    For sht2row = 2 To sht2total

        If DupID = Cells(sht2row, 1).Value Then

            Rows(sht2row).Delete
            sht2row = sht2row - 1
            Exit For

        End If

    Next

    sht1row = sht1row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```